Are there any instances of Christians fasting on pagan holidays besides the Kalends?
I'm interested if early Christians fasted on pagan festivals because I've read some primary sources that instruct Christians to fast on the New Year's aka the Kalends of January but I couldn't find any other sources regarding fasting on any other pagan festivals by early Christians. Here are the sources I've read:

“Moreover, in the other times, that is, on the Kalends of January, which are observed due to the error of paganism, alleluia shall not be sung at all. During these days, besides fish and vegetables, just as in Lent, abstention from meat is observed, and by some, even wine is not drunk. Therefore, if any bishop, priest, deacon, or anyone from the order of the clergy is found to follow their own judgement before this decree, he shall be compelled to be deprived of the duties of his office and be deprived of Paschal Communion."- Council of Toledo, Canon 11


“In regard to the fasts of monks……….Every day between Christmas and Epiphany is a festival day, and they all will have banquets except for those three days that our fathers have established for treading upon the custom of the pagans, on the Kalends of January. On those days, they shall have private litanies performed in the church, at the eighth hour celebrate the Mass of the Circumcision on the very first day of January”- Council of Tours, Canon 18


“Are you going to take part in a celebration of the New Year? Are you, just like a pagan, going to play dice and become intoxicated when you believe, hope, and love otherwise?………When they give gifts, do you give alms. They are called away by songs of license; you, by the discourses of the Scriptures. They run to the theatre; you, to the church. They become intoxicated; do you fast. If you are not able to fast today, at least dine in moderation. If you have acted thus, then you have rightly sung: 'Save us, O Lord our God: and gather us from among the nations.”- Augustine of Hippo, Sermon 198


"The fast of the Kalends of January was instituted by the Church because of the error of the Gentiles. For Janus there was a certain leader of the pagans, from whom the name of the month of January is derived, which unlearned men, worshiping as God, handed down to posterity in the religion of honor, and sanctified the day itself with scenes and luxury…… Accordingly, therefore, the holy Fathers, considering that the greatest part of the human race were to serve such sacrileges and lusts on the same day, instituted a public fast in the whole world through all the Churches, by which they might acknowledge that men were acting wrongly to such an extent that it was necessary for all the Churches to fast for their sins."- Isidore of Seville, De ecclesiasticis officiis Ch. 41


“On the very eve of this feast there also are some simple men who set their little tables full of many things which are necessary to eat, and they want to keep them arranged this way throughout the night, believing that in this way the Calends of January can benefit them, so that throughout the year their banquets will continue with such plenty……..Throughout all the churches a public fast was imposed, so that those miserable men might realize that they had committed such a great evil that it was necessary for all the churches to fast on account of their sins. For this reason, dearest brethren, let us fast on these days, and with a true and perfect charity let us grieve over the foolishness of miserable men, so that they may understand their wickedness as they see a public fast being observed for them."- Caesarius of Arles, Sermon 192


“How then can you religiously celebrate the Epiphany of the Lord, those who celebrate Janus as much as is in you most devoutly?  For Janus was a man, the founder of a city, which is called Janiculus, in whose honor the heathens are called Januaries; Hence he who worships the Janus sins, because he brings the homage of the divinity to a dead man…..For he observed the day and the month that he either did not fast during these days or did not go to church. He observed the day that he did not go to church the day before but went to the field. Therefore, brothers, let us decline with all diligence the festivals and holidays of the Gentiles, so that when they feast and are happy, now let us be sober and fast, so that they may understand that their joy is condemned by our abstinence.”- Maximus of Turin, Sermon 63 ”On the Kalends of January


this one may be a starting point: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/86869/what-pagan-elements-were-adopted-in-christianity

Many Christian Holidays origins come from Pagan origins.  Christmas / Sol Invictus,  New Years Day Jan 1/  Roman consul Quintus Fulvius Nobilior move New Years Day to Jan 1 153 BC.  Easter from Eostre,  The Germanic goddess of Spring,  that's how we got easter bunnies and eggs.  Labor Day / For the Romans, May 1st was dedicated to Maia, an ancient goddess associated with the element of fire and with fertility. The entire month was - and still is - named after her.

Thanks but I'm not interested co-opting pagan festivals into Christian ones but more interested in Christians fasting on pagan festivals though

@JMS I think OP's point is that this is the opposite of that. The various Canons and statements are saying "on this day the pagans celebrate with a feast - good Christians should fast" (ie, deprive themselves and not eat or enjoy the party) -- and honestly, it's kind of interesting that the early Christians were so against this particular celebration that they created an anti-feast to mark it, given how many other pagan traditions they co-opted.

My previous comment also applies to @DanM

@codeMonkey the comments are starting point; my reasoning would be: 1) which are the matching festivities between pagans and christians? 2) how those matching are handled by christian and pagan?

@codeMonkey, Yes interesting.  Christianity was just the latest example of Rome desperately trying to unify the empire by integrating foreign religions.  First they (Romans) defined what it meant to be Christian (Aug 325 AD).  Casting their nets wide by adopting pagan holidays to make Christianity more palatable to a population more accustomed to killing them.  Finally, they hunted down and murdered or persecuted any Christian or Pagan who didn't sign up to the new definition.   Also interesting is the official definition of Christianity remained in flux for the next 100 years.
